# How to have a class with an instance of its predecessor and continue its heirarchy for all new instances?

Tags: c++, user-interface, geometry, structure, coordinates

I'll try to be as specific as possible so it's easy to understand.

Let's say you have a class that holds a rectangle in the form of `(x, y, w, h)` when working on a 2d plane with `(0,0)` being the top left of the display. The first instance of this class holds the values `(0,0,1920,1080)`, which sets the display dimensions for a program.

Now, from here, I want to have all the next instances of `Rectangle` to exist within the previous one, such that their coordinates act as relative positions to it.

For example, let's work with the next 2 `Rectangle` instances. I'll declare one called **rect1** to have the values `(100,100,500,500)`, and then the second instance called **rect2** to exist within **rect1**. Its values will be `(50,50,50,50)`.

Now, I want the heirarchy of values to apply to all instances to allow the relative positioning. What this would mean is that **(relative to the original display's rectangle's first instance)**, **rect1** will have a relative position `in the form (x,y)` of `(100,100)`, however **rect2** will have a relative position of `(150,150)` **TO THE ORIGINAL DISPLAY'S RECTANGLE's FIRST INSTANCE**.

But, to make life easy and follow the heirarchy, **rect2** will have a **RELATIVE POSITION TO rect1** of `(50,50)`, yet in terms of the predasessor of **rect1**, its relative position is `(150,150)`, as explained before.

Here is a picture of what I am trying to demonstrate:

[image: here]

So, with that type of structure in mind, how would I be able to translate that concept into code that follows the same idea?

Comment: Seems like you need two abstractions, one for the shape types and one for frames, which can contain objects and are positioned relative to other frames.

Comment: Would a `Rectangle* align_against;` member variable do the trick? Whenever you paint a rectangle it can do `auto px = left, py = top; if(align_against) { px += align_against->left; py += align_against->top; } paint(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest method is to store a reference to the "parent" `Rectangle`. So given you example it would look something like this:

When you are looking for the relative location you would simply need to check if the parent is null and return the positions added to the parents:

```cpp
class Rectangle {
private:
  int x, y, w, h;
  Rectangle *parent;

public:
  Point getLocation() {
    if (this.parent != NULL) {
      // return x and y
    }
    // return x + this.parent.x and y + this.parent.y
  }

  int getXOffset() {
    if (this.parent != NULL) {
      return this.x + this.parent->getXOffset();
    }

    return this.x;
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

Note that for this structure to work properly you will want to implement methods (`getXOffset()` for example) to walk the parent hierarchy to recursively sum the offset of every parent `Rectangle` rather than directlry accessing the registered parent and missing 'grandparents' or even 'grand grandparents'.

Comment: Is `void getLocation()` a method or just a function that doesn't exist in the class `Rectangle`?

Comment: It should be a method, I;ll update it so everything is a bit more clear

Comment: If the `Rectangle *parent` is private, how do I make sure it points to the correct instance?

Comment: Pass it in the constructor. Ive omitted the constructors for brevity's sake, and you should be able to figure out how to set all that up with a little research :)

Comment: Okay, I guess my concern there is what if I want to create an instance of `Rectangle` within a class declaration of a header. That way I can't actually pass in the parent?

Comment: Then pass in the parent rather than have a parent member pointer.  `int getXOffset(Rectangle* parent) { if (parent != nullptr) { return x + parent->getXOffset(); } return x; }`

Comment: No i mean, like in an entirely different class, when that class has its own members, if I need it to also have a member that is a `Rectangle`, when I declare it I can't construct it? Side note: Do i actually need to call `this`? can't i just call `parent->`?

Comment: Define some super class for everything like `Shape` which has those `getLocation` and `getOffset` method and take a shape for everything that would need a rectangle in the examples